# is it possible to set a maximum number of result on autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using `autocomplete` of `jQuery UI` : excellent plugin!

The only thing I don't like is that, if I have a list of `40 items`, I'd like to show only `10 items`.

This is my actual code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var availableTags = [<%= m_strTags %>];
        $("#myTags").autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
            max: 20
        });
    });
</script>
```

Is it possible put some parameters to do this thing?

Comment: The autcomplete uses a remote file to handle the results, right?

Comment: It seems there is no easy way to do this. You should set this server-side

Comment: I can't do it : the list is static, I don't update it dinamically...

Comment: Oh sorry I thought otherwise...  =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want to modify the source list, you could try scrollable results:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#maxheight

Answer (score 3):

From the migration guide:

> max: Gone; if your server sends too
>   many items, pass a function for the
>   source option that calls $.ajax and
>   truncates or filters the resulting
>   list.

http://www.learningjquery.com/2010/06/autocomplete-migration-guide

Answer (score 2):

You can try implementing your own filter function by using a callback function as a source. Something like:

```
$('input').autocomplete({
    source : function (request, response) {

        var max = 10;    // set this to something
        var j = 0;

        response($.map(availableTags, function(i) {
            if (j < max && i.toLowerCase().indexOf(request.term.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
                j++; return { label : i };
            } else { 
                return null;
            }   
        }));
    }
});
```

This is basically trying to check each of the elements in your string array, and performing a case-insensitive `contains` search. You may want to modify it to check only for `startsWith` or `endsWith` or whatever you have. Of course, you may also want to use `regex` instead to speed things up a bit.

I also setup a quick example here : http://jsfiddle.net/2exCC/
Try searching for something like `C`. This should return up to `scala`, and leave behind `scheme`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a nasty solution, and you really should look for a nicer one, but if you won't find anything you can hide the `.ui-menu-item`'s when autocomplete opens popup with suggestions (`open` event).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.  You need to use the setOptions() function.

Example:

```
$('input#suggest').setOptions({
 max: 15
});
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/setOptions#options

Comment: This is not the jQuery UI plugins; it should be deprecated, isnt it? http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/